# Automatically recognising datetime in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I am trying to subtract two timeseries to get a difference in time.

The source data in *train.csv* looks like

```
id,vendor_id,pickup_datetime,dropoff_datetime
id2875421,2,2016-03-14 17:24:55,2016-03-14 17:32:30
id2377394,1,2016-06-12 00:43:35,2016-06-12 00:54:38
```

My code is

```
train = pd.read_csv('./train.csv')
out = train.dropoff_datetime[0:5] - train.dropoff_datetime[0:5]
```

I get an error which ends in:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'
```

Presumably this is because the datetime columns are being stored as objects or strings rather than as datetime objects. In some installations pandas is able to automatically recognize date columns such as this. How can this be set up? My experience is that pandas unpredictably recognizes the date column in different formats. What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

I am using Python 3.6 and pandas 0.20 in a jupyter notebook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Automatic parsing datetimes columns without no specifying them is not possible in pandas.

You need define columns for parsing to datetime by positions in parameter `parse_dates` in [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html):

```
train = pd.read_csv('./train.csv', parse_dates=[2,3])
```

Or by columns names:

```
train = pd.read_csv('./train.csv', parse_dates=['pickup_datetime','dropoff_datetime'])
```

---

```
print (train.dtypes)
id                          object
vendor_id                    int64
pickup_datetime     datetime64[ns]
dropoff_datetime    datetime64[ns]
dtype: object

out=train.dropoff_datetime[0:5]-train.pickup_datetime[0:5]
print (out)
0   00:07:35
1   00:11:03
dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

For new column:

```
train['difference']=train.dropoff_datetime-train.pickup_datetime
print (train)
          id  vendor_id     pickup_datetime    dropoff_datetime difference
0  id2875421          2 2016-03-14 17:24:55 2016-03-14 17:32:30   00:07:35
1  id2377394          1 2016-06-12 00:43:35 2016-06-12 00:54:38   00:11:03
```

Comment: the comment specifies automatic parsing. there is nothing automatic if the function requires user given indices/names of the date columns.

Comment: @VarunRajan - Ya, thank you for comment after downvote. In my opinion automatic parsing datetimes columns without no specifying them is not possible.

Comment: @VarunRajan - I add this to answer, I hope now it is OK.

Comment: @VarunRajan - Btw, your comment is really nice form me, because obviously downvoter wants to be hidden, +3

Comment: yeah. there is no point if you have to critic something if you do not provide justification for the same. appreciate the sportsmanship. as for what you mentioned with respect to automation not being possible, i have implemented a way you Can do the same. that was the specific reason why i downvoted. Different ways to do it would be;

Comment: regex matching on column names with 'date' or some pattern in the string after reading in file and then apply datetime, or pass all column indices to dateparser and create a function for the parser that tries to coerce all columns to date, and on error continue to next column, or another convenient method being reading the file as an xlsx which helps pandas automatically infer which the date columns are

Answer (score 1):

```
train = pd.read_csv('./train.csv')
>>>> train.assign(out=pd.to_datetime(train.dropoff_datetime) - pd.to_datetime(train.pickup_datetime))
          id  vendor      pickup_datetime     dropoff_datetime      out
0  id2875421       1  2016-03-14 17:24:55  2016-03-14 17:32:30 00:07:35
1  id2377394       2  2016-06-12 00:43:35  2016-06-12 00:54:38 00:11:03
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer by @jezrael is good.

Also, the following would work.

```
train = pd.read_csv('./train.csv')
train['dropoff_datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(train.dropoff_datetime)
train['pickup_datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(train.pickup_datetime)
```

Comment: This does work now. I could have sworn that I ran this exact code before. Is there any reason that pandas runs differently on the same code? I guess not. I must have missed something.